# (Python) name 'curr' is not defined

Tags: python, flask, error-handling

```
@socketio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect_details():
    for room_num in room_users_counter:
        curr = 0
        expected_num = room_users_counter[room_num]
        emit(f"{room_num}$attendance", broadcast=True, include_self=False)
        @socketio.on("here")
        def here(_room_num):
            global curr
         
            if _room_num == room_num:
                curr +=1
```

**Error:**

```
line 246, in here
    curr +=1
NameError: name 'curr' is not defined
```

I don't know why its undefined when I defined by saying `curr = 0` at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `nonlocal`, not `global` since `curr` is a local variable (local to `disconnect_details`), not a global one.

```
def here(_room_num):
    nonlocal curr
     
    if _room_num == room_num:
        curr += 1
```